# Running FreeSSHd fails as Administrator on Windows 10

Tags: windows-installer

After installing FreeSSHd on Windows 10, run as Administrator to open FreeSSHd, it pops up a message: "You don't have administrator rights! freeSSHd will close!"
I check the right, I am the administrator.

Comment: Is this a shortcut you are launching from? If the shortcut is on the desktop, try right clicking it and selecting **`Run as Administrator`**. If it is in the start menu, right click it and select: **`More`** => **`Run as Administrator`**.

Comment: Please provide more information about how you are checking for admin rights and other details about your problem, so people can provide accurate answers.

Comment: @Stein Asmul, yes, click the right key and click the Run as Administrator, also pop up message: ou don't have administrator rights! freeSSHd will close!

Comment: @peeyushsingh Run the command line with “ran as administrator”， it's Okay, but try right clicking it and selecting Run as Administrator for the shortcut of FreeSSHd, it's faile

Comment: You must be logged in as a regular user. Try **`Windows Key`** => Tap **`R`** => **`cmd.exe`** => **`Enter`**. Type this command (use your user name where the placeholder is): **`net user <username>`**. Check whether you have the group membership for administrators. Maybe also try to right click the clock in the system tray and see if you are allowed to change the time - that should be blocked for a standard users.